# Run a regression on two categorical factors

Tags: r, regression, lm

I would like to run an LM on a time series data set that I have collated.

One of the variables `X?` is categoric: that of geographic **Region**: Middle East, Eastern Europe, North Africa etc..

```
MyModel <- lm(Y ~ X1 + x2 + x3, Data = mydataset)
```

Currently, I have been able to run my model as separate regressions for each categoric variable - **Region** see data below using the following code.

```
Model1MEAST&EE<- y ~ B1X1 + B2X2 +  B3X3 + factor(COND$name) + factor(COND$Year), data=mydataset, Region==  "Middle East")).
```

Which works fine.

Now I would like to run a regression but on two or more Regions combined but still leaving out all other regions, so, for example, a regression on  **Middle East** and **East Europe** countries only say.

I have tried using the '+' command and the 'c' and 'list' command with the above code but that does not seem to work. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZxuZ.png)
Can anyone provide the code for running a regression on two categoric factors combined not just the one?

I have included  a link to an image of just a small RANDOM sample (only 4 variables) of my dataset, taken from my time series study for every country over 35 years with 50 plus economic and development indicator variables, such as  GDP; I have made the categoric variable for which I which I would like to combine two regions in a subset regression in **BOLD**.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided usable data of some sort.

Comment: More precisely, what is mydataset?

Comment: Sorry,  it is a very large dataset > more 7000 rows across 50 plus variable columns. it is a time series for a number of economic / development indicators for every country-year over 34 years. I have provided a r data file with just a snippet of some o fthe variable columns including the one in question (

Comment: x1= Country Name,  x2 Region, x3 Year, x4 FiscalIB, .........are the first three columns. x2 currently is categoric and I would like to run a regression two of the factor regions I can do one but I would like to run a regression on data from two regions. As I say I have a very small R.data file.

Comment: You have provided the dataset where? Please `dput` a representative sample of the data in your question

Comment: structure(list(name = c("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Azerbaijan", 
"Belize", "Botswana", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", 
"Egypt, Arab Rep.", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Fiji", "Isle of Man", 
"Israel"), Region = c("South Asia", "Southern Africa", "Central Asia", 
"South America", "Southern Africa", "Central Africa", "North America", 
"Caribbean", "South America", "North Africa", "East Africa", 
"Eastern Europe", "Australasia", "Western Europe", "Middle East"
), Year = c(1980, 1990, 1994, 2001, 1997, 2014, 1980, 2014, 1980, 
2014, 2014, 1992, 2014, 2014, 1980)

Comment: Above is the Dput output of the first three variables for the data set. Apologies if I am not providing you with what you nee,  I have only been using R for a month or so so much of this is new. I do have 2 kb R.data file which is a very small snippet of my data - only 5 variables including region and about15 rows -but I am not sure how/if i can attach it in this post.

Comment: have added an image of my sample dataset table in the original question

Answer (score 2):

### Dummy Variables!

What I would do first is: create dummy variable columns using the `fastDummies` package.

***Example***: `df <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "Region")`

If you wish to leave one of the dummy columns out for the sake of neater regression running, you can add an extra argument (trivial explanation: removes most frequent of the categorical variables):

`df <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "Region", remove_most_frequent_dummy = TRUE)`

### Subset

If you wish to subset your data you can split by index finding

`ind <- which(df$Region == "Middle East" | df$Region == "East Europe")`

and then creating a new dataframe consisting solely of the **Middle East** and **European** rows.

`newdf <- df[ind, ]`

Once you have done this you can run a regression remembering to exclude one of your dummy variables.

***Example***: `lm(data = mydataset, Y ~ Xi + Middle East)`

### Alternatively

Instead of splitting your data you can run all of your dummied variables (except one) in your regression such that you only have one model. Determining which way is better will come down to a combination of sample size availability as well as logical arguments for splitting/not splitting e.g. do we expect GDP to influence unemployment rates the same way across the world? If yes, then it might be good to have a full model. If not, then splitting may be the better direction.